# How to remove spaces within brackets on dynamic properties for objects

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I do have such a code
[image]
where I get spaces within the square brackets for the dynamic properties of an object.
I could not find any Settings under `Code Style/Typescript/Spaces` to adjust this.
Are they hidden somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to adjust this is in `Code Style/TypeScript/Spaces`. Look in `Within` section: `Index access brackets`.  (WebStorm 2020.3.2)